# Javascript - "concatenate" with a variable in a for loop

Tags: javascript, variables, loops, for-loop, concatenation

I am not really sure about the therm I use in my title, but here we go.

So I have something like that:

```
for (var key in myObject) {

var GivenName = theObject.PS_1.GivenName;
var GivenName = theObject.PS_2.GivenName;
var GivenName = theObject.PS_3.GivenName;
var GivenName = theObject.PS_4.GivenName;
// and so on...

}
```

So obviously I don't wanna write everything like that, I need to use the var Key, but I didn't figure how the hell I am supposed to do that, I tried alof of thing, but I failed everytime, yes I'am bad and I should feel bad.

I tried this:

```
var GivenName = 'theObject.'+key+'.FirstName';
var GivenName = theObject.key.FirstName;
var GivenName = theObject.[key].FirstName;
var GivenName = theObject.['key'].FirstName;
var GivenName = theObject.[+key+].FirstName;
```

btw the Key var contain PS_1 then PS_2 then PS_3...

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var GivenName = theObject[key].FirstName;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var key in myObject) {
    var value = myObject[key];
}
```

http://eloquentjavascript.net

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't had a chance to read it yet the mozilla javascript documentation is absolutely awesome.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Even if you are familiar with most of it it will still provide excellent reference info. From the docs:

> Object properties names can be valid JavaScript string, or anything
>   that can be converted to string, including the empty string. However,
>   any property name that is not a valid JavaScript identifier (for
>   example, a property name that has space or dash, or starts with a
>   number) can only be accessed using the square bracket notation. This
>   notation is also very useful when property names are to be dynamically
>   determined (when the property name is not determined until runtime).
>   Examples are as follows:

```
var myObj = new Object(),
    str = "myString",
    rand = Math.random(),
    obj = new Object();

myObj.type              = "Dot syntax";
myObj["date created"]   = "String with space";
myObj[str]              = "String value";
myObj[rand]             = "Random Number";
myObj[obj]              = "Object";
myObj[""]               = "Even an empty string";

console.log(myObj);
```